# How to get columns of a datatable by column number or position

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I know how to get it by using a simple for each loop as shown below. Can you show me how to get it by position/index/column number ?

```
foreach (DataRow row_ in dt.Rows){
  row = row_;
  foreach (DataColumn col_ in dt.Columns){
    col = col_;
    strMsg = strMsg + col.ColumnName + ": " + row[col.Ordinal].ToString() 
             + Environment.NewLine;
  }
  MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
  strMsg = "";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm clear about what you want to do but why don't you use DataReader to get specific column you want? Thats going to return results to you row by row.

Comment: @curiousBoy - Instead of using that foreach to get a data column, i want to use something like this for(DataColumnAtIndex[index]){//code}.

Comment: yourGrid.Columns.IndexOf(col), something like this?

Comment: @curiousBoy - thanks. but I want to use a datatable. Is there a similar method for that ?

Comment: You can look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511576/getting-index-of-a-value-in-datatable  hope it helps

Comment: I don't think that will work. Let me clarify - I have columns in this order Col1,col2,Col3... I want to get the column and 7th position. so, I am looking for something like DataColumn dc = myDataTable.Column(7); Is that possible ?

Comment: does `myDataTable.Columns[7]` not work?

Comment: Have you tried getting them in to a  DataColumnCollection your_columns = yourTable.Columns; then get the index of that collection? That might work

Comment: @Vlad - yes it does. thanks ! also, how do i get the number of columns ?

Comment: @blasto `myDataTable.Columns.Count` or `myDataTable.Columns.Count()` with Linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the ordinal via `IndexOf`. Here it is in your example:

```
foreach (DataRow row_ in dt.Rows) {
  row = row_;
  foreach (DataColumn col_ in dt.Columns) {
    col = col_;
    strMsg = strMsg + col.ColumnName + ": " + row[dt.Columns.IndexOf(col_)].ToString() 
         + Environment.NewLine;
  }
  MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
  strMsg = "";
}
```

And here is a fully working sample:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());

var row1 = dt.NewRow();
row1[0] = "0";
row1[1] = "1";
dt.Rows.Add(row1);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        var strMsg = col.ColumnName + ": " + row[dt.Columns.IndexOf(col)].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(strMsg);
    }
}
```

If you just want the column names in an array, remove the `foreach` loops and replace them with this line:

```
string[] colNames = (from DataColumn col in dt.Columns select col.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get all the column names into an array, without iterating over rows ?

Comment: Sure, remove the `foreach` loops altogether and replace them with this line: `string[] colNames = (from DataColumn col in dt.Columns select col.ColumnName).ToArray();`

Comment: If I don't remove the DataColumns, then will there be any problems ?

Comment: No problem, removing the loops doesn't affect the other logic.