# Return line and column Index of a value that exists in dataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, indexof

This solution provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703320/check-if-value-exists-in-datatable) was really helpful:

```
DataColumn[] columns = tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
bool anyFieldContainsPepsi = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .Any(row => columns.Any(col => row[col].ToString() == "PEPSI"));
```

- But I need to return, instead of bool, the index of the "found" value. Should I try [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511576/getting-index-of-a-value-in-datatable)? Note that I do need the Line Number/Index and the Column Number/Index.

---

My code at this point:

```
    bool find = csvDataOnlyHeader.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(r => r.ItemArray.Any(c => c.ToString().Contains("SN:")));

    DataColumn[] columns = csvDataOnlyHeader.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
    bool anyFieldContains = csvDataOnlyHeader.AsEnumerable()
        .Any(row => columns.Any(col => row[col].ToString() == "SN:"));
```

What do I need:

1. Search the whole DataTable for a specific string (not caring about columns name or position).
2. Return the Index (or Indexes) of the places that contains this string. (I.e. line 2 column 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the row index using the `IndexOf` method of the `DataRowCollection` type or like @StriplingWarrior pointed out the index parameter of the lambda expression if the index of the row in the original enumerable is reliable enough for you.

```
var columns = tbl.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
var enumerableRowCollection = tbl.AsEnumerable();

var results = enumerableRowCollection
    .Select((row, index) =>
    {
        var column = columns.FirstOrDefault(col => row[col].ToString() == "PEPSI");

        return new
        {
            Column = column,
            ColumnIndex = column != null ? columns.IndexOf(column) : -1,
            Row = row,
            RowIndex = index
        };
    })
    .Where(x => x.Column != null)
    .ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
{
    var result = results[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"Result {i}");
    Console.WriteLine($"RowIndex: {result.RowIndex}");
    Console.WriteLine($"ColumnIndex: {result.ColumnIndex}");
}
```

Comment: This is working well. Is there any way of getting also the column Index? In my case, I need the exact position. For example Row 3 Position 4 (Position = Column)

Comment: Added expanded version of the example to retrieve column index.

Comment: Thank you for the update. One last thing, in the "ColumnIndex = columns.IndexOf(x.Column)," the "Indexof" part is presenting the error "No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: Did two updates [1] RowIndex is now coming from the first projection and [2] changed the very first line to convert to list. And [3] refactored into single projection call to combine all the data in the result.

Comment: Hey, still... the "ColumnIndex = columns.IndexOf(column)," presents the error "No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments". Now, I also have another error in the part "DataColumn[] columns = csvDataOnlyHeader.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();" - Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataColumn>' to 'System.Data.DataColumn[]'

Comment: It should be good now, sorry about the bug. `IndexOf` is only available in the `List<T>` generic type. One more fix to check for the null of the column inside the expression body.

Comment: Awesome! It works really well. Thank you for helping and the updates.

Answer (score 1):

There's a variant of `Select` that allows you to capture an index.

```
var matchingIndexes = csvDataOnlyHeader.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select((r, index) => new 
        {
            isMatch = r.ItemArray.Any(c => c.ToString().Contains("SN:")),
            index
        })
    .Where(e => e.isMatch)
    .Select(e => e.index);
var firstMatch = matchingIndexes.FirstOrDefault();
```

To avoid ambiguity between `firstMatch` having a `0` (meaning the first match is the zeroth element of the array) and `0` (meaning there were no matching indexes), you could cast the results as nullable ints:

```
...
.Select(e => (int?)e.index)
...
```

Or you can use my [CallMeMaybe](https://github.com/j2jensen/callmemaybe) library to get a `Maybe<int>`:

```
var firstMatch = matchingIndexes.FirstMaybe();
```

Comment: Hey, if I try like this, var firstMatch is returning "0". However, both "bool checks" are returning "true". In my case, "bool find" and "bool anyFieldContains". Both return true as if they found the "SN:" value.

Comment: If the first bool check returns true, then matchingIndexes should contain `[0, 1]`, right? `matchingIndexes.FirstOrDefault()` would return `0`, which is correct: zero is the first index of an item that matches in your datatable.

Comment: @FabioSoares: I added to my answer, to show how you can avoid ambiguity using nullables.

Comment: The matchingIndexes is returning "[0] = 0" -> (new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<int>(matchingIndexes)).Items[0]. On the other hand, the bool find it returning "true". For both I am looking for "SN:"

Comment: If you want to check the steps, I put some screenshots: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B98UpTa2n4XbeHZtOHU2cVotUms?usp=sharing

Comment: @FabioSoares: It looks like your data table's first row contains row headers, and one of the row headers has "SN:" in it, so the first row (at index 0) matches your criteria. You originally just said you wanted the index (which I took to mean the row index). Since you clarified that you need the column index as well, this answer is probably not sufficient for what you're looking for.